# How to escape an apostrophe in recsel?

Tags: gnu

Let's consider the following recfile

```
Name: John
Text: It's me!

Name: Jane
Text: Hello
```

The following command works perfectly to select the second record

```
recsel -e "Text = 'Hello'" test.rec
```

but how to select the first one?

```
recsel -e "Text = 'It\'s me!'" test.rec
```

is not working even if according the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/manual/SEX-Operands.html#SEX-Operands) (section 3.5.2.2 String Literals) it's the correct syntax.

I am using GNU Recutils version 1.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a matter of shell quoting rather than `recsel` specifically.

The `!` in your record text adds an extra complication (at least in an interactive bash shell) - without it, you could use escaped double quotes within double quotes, which remove the special meaning of any single quotes inside. Turning off history expansion to demonstrate:

```
$ set +o histexpand
$ recsel -e "Text = \"It's me!\"" test.rec
Name: John
Text: It's me!
```

Otherwise, you can use outer single quotes, closing and reopening them around the literal single quote:

```
$ recsel -e 'Text = "It'\''s me!"' test.rec
Name: John
Text: It's me!
```